# Get the height of virtual keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

How can I get the height of virtual keyboard in Android? Is it possible?

I try to get it from the main window, but it gives me full height of the application. But I want to get the keyboard height.

Comment: The soft keyboard isn't the only system-supplied decoration that can consume screen space. What do you intend to do with this size?

Comment: I want to draw some images top of the soft virtualkeyboard. I develop 2D application, so I dont use android UI library. for example, I want to draw border top of the soft keyboard

Comment: Doesn't the virtual keyboard push the window upwards? In that case, all you need is a line at the bottom of the screen to draw a top border (that's set to invisible until softkeyboard is activated)

Comment: It only pushes the window upwards if it is not in fullscreen.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566595/13642440).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the keyboard height, but you can get the height of your View, which is what you really want - and you'll get this data supplied to the onLayout call into the current view.

Comment: my view gives full height of device. so, this info doesnt give virtual keyboard height. but, I found a way to get it. After I request to open virtual keyboard, I send pointer event that I generate. their y coordinate starts from height of device and decreases. and, after I send these event to system, system throws exception when pointer event is on virtual keyboard. if these pointer events is not on virtual keyboard, there is no exception. so I can get height of virtual keyboard.

Comment: It is actually for android models with navigationbar?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this sample code. it is dirty solution but it works

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                int y = mainScreenView.getHeight()-2;
                int x = 10;
                int counter = 0;
                int height = y;
                while (true){
                    final MotionEvent m = MotionEvent.obtain(
                            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                            x, 
                            y,
                            INTERNAL_POINTER_META_STATE);
                    final MotionEvent m1 = MotionEvent.obtain(
                            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                            x, 
                            y,
                            INTERNAL_POINTER_META_STATE);
                    boolean pointer_on_softkeyboard = false;
                    try {
                        getSingletonInstrumentation().sendPointerSync(m);
                        getSingletonInstrumentation().sendPointerSync(m1);
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        pointer_on_softkeyboard = true;
                    }
                    if (!pointer_on_softkeyboard){
                        if (y == height){
                            if (counter++ < 100){
                                Thread.yield();
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else if (y > 0){
                            softkeyboard_height = mainScreenView.getHeight() - y;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    y--;

                }
                if (softkeyboard_height > 0 ){
                    // it is calculated and saved in softkeyboard_height
                } else {
                    calculated_keyboard_height = false;
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

Comment: Where is INTERNAL_POINTER_META_STATE? metaState is referred to KeyEvent API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState() but INTERNAL_POINTER_META_STATE is nowhere to be found.

Comment: INTERNAL_POINTER_META_STATE is just a id that identify this event sources. so you can track which pointer event are generated by you or by device. you should just set a integer value to INTERNAL_POINTER_META_STATE

Comment: What is getSingletonInstrumentation() method?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is also hacky but solve the problem (atleast for me).

1. I have places on temporary view with transparent background at the bottom of the screen. So this view will be invisible.
2. I have added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` flag in activity tag in manifest.
3. Now main story is in `onGlobalLayout()`. There i calculate the difference between the y axis of temp view and height of root view

   final View view = findViewById(R.id.base);
       view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {

       int rootViewHeight = view.getRootView().getHeight();
       View tv = findViewById(R.id.temp_view);
       int location[] = new int[2];
       tv.getLocationOnScreen(location);
       int height = (int) (location[1] + tv.getMeasuredHeight());
       deff = rootViewHeight - height;
       // deff is the height of soft keyboard

   }
   ```

   });

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your app.
You can try something like this:

```
    any_view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int height = main_layout.getHeight();
            Log.w("Foo", String.format("layout height: %d", height));
            Rect r = new Rect();
            main_layout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int visible = r.bottom - r.top;
            Log.w("Foo", String.format("visible height: %d", visible));
            Log.w("Foo", String.format("keyboard height: %d", height - visible));
        }
    });
```

Comment: getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame doesnt work for me..it returns the Height of the View

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that the rootView of your layout is RelativeLayout.
What you can do create a class CustomRelativeLayout which extends RelativeLayout and
Overrides onSizeChanged Method inside it.
So when the soft keyboard opens up, the height of the RelativeLayout will change and the 
change will be notified inside the onSizeChanged Method.

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    int softKeyboardHeight = oldh - h; // Assuming softKeyboard Opened up
    // oldh is the height when the layout was covering the whole screen
    // h is the new height of the layout when the soft keyboard opened up

    if(softKeyboardHeight > oldh * 0.15) {
        Log.i("Here", Integer.toString(softKeyboardHeight));
        // Keyboard has popped up

    } else {
        // Not the keyboard
    }
}
```

In your Manifest file make these changes so that the Activity opens in Resize Mode and Not pan and scan mode. In Resize mode the Layout will be able to resize when keybaord opens up.
To read more about pan-scan and Resize visit
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
KeyboardView keyboardView = new KeyboardView(getApplicationContext(), null);
int height = (keyboardView.getKeyboard()).getHeight();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), height+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Looks so wonderful simple, just two lines of code... But it doesn't work for me `keyboardView.getKeyboard()` returns `null`

Comment: Same for me too ..keyboardView.getKeyboard() returns null

Comment: Might not be so accurate but if you don't need a listener its better to use this one.