# How to send out pointer event in Android

Tags: android, events, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to detect the virtual keyboard height in Android.

I found a similar topic: [Get the height of virtual keyboard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009487/get-height-of-virtualkeyboard-in-android)

It seems the author found a way to detect the height:

> I found a way to get it. After I request to open virtual keyboard, I
>   send pointer event that I generate. their y coordinate starts from
>   height of device and decreases.

I don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be using the code provided at the link that you posted:

```
// Declare Variables

int softkeyboard_height = 0;
boolean calculated_keyboard_height;
Instrumentation instrumentation;

// Initialize instrumentation sometime before starting the thread
instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
```

`mainScreenView` is your base view, your activity's view. `m`(ACTION_DOWN) and `m1`(ACTION_UP) are touch events that are dispatched using `Instrumentation#sendPointerSync(MotionEvent)`. The logic is that a MotionEvent dispatched to where the keyboard is being displayed will cause the following `SecurityException`:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires
>   INJECT_EVENTS permission

So, we start at the bottom of the screen and make our way up (by decrementing `y`) on every iteration of the loop. For certain number of iterations, we will get a SecurityException (which we'll catch): this would imply that the MotionEvent is happening over the keyboard. The moment `y` gets small enough (when its just above the keyboard), we'll break out of the loop and calculate the keyboard's height using:

```
softkeyboard_height = mainScreenView.getHeight() - y;
```

Code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            int y = mainScreenView.getHeight()-2;
            int x = 10;
            int counter = 0;
            int height = y;
            while (true){
                final MotionEvent m = MotionEvent.obtain(
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        x, 
                        y,
                        1);
                final MotionEvent m1 = MotionEvent.obtain(
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                        x, 
                        y,
                        1);
                boolean pointer_on_softkeyboard = false;
                try {
                    instrumentation.sendPointerSync(m);
                    instrumentation.sendPointerSync(m1);
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    pointer_on_softkeyboard = true;
                }
                if (!pointer_on_softkeyboard){
                    if (y == height){
                        if (counter++ < 100){
                            Thread.yield();
                            continue;
                        }
                    } else if (y > 0){
                        softkeyboard_height = mainScreenView.getHeight() - y;
                        Log.i("", "Soft Keyboard's height is: " + softkeyboard_height);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                y--;

            }
            if (softkeyboard_height > 0 ){
                // it is calculated and saved in softkeyboard_height
            } else {
                calculated_keyboard_height = false;
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

`Instrumentation#sendPointerSync(MotionEvent)`:

> Dispatch a pointer event. Finished at some point after the recipient
>   has returned from its event processing, though it may not have
>   completely finished reacting from the event -- for example, if it
>   needs to update its display as a result, it may still be in the
>   process of doing that.

Comment: Is this a public API? I can't find documentation about `INTERNAL_POINTER_META_STATE`.

Comment: @rid Sorry about that. `INTERNAL_POINTER_META_STATE` is an integer constant. For the question's purpose, using any integer value would work. I have edited the code above. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Still, is it safe to use this without the functionality having a chance to disappear in any future version of Android? Is that `1` guaranteed to always be the same? Is it documented anywhere officially by Google? Can you rely on this without fear of producing brittle code?

Comment: @rid About this functionality disappearing any time soon: I would guess `no`. The SecurityException that we are counting on is thrown because of a missing permission: `INJECT_EVENTS`. This permission can only be obtained by system apps: Romain Guy confirms this [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8422). `Can you rely on this without fear of producing brittle code?` Strictly speaking, this is a stereotypical hack. Use it, but be ready for when it lets up.

Comment: @rid The `1` is there for face-value. It does not take part in the program's logic. It maps to `KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON`. If you'd feel better using a value that isn't mapped, use zero. But I can't recommend a value since they're all just filling the .... That sixth argument can take values of the form KeyEvent.META_X. Shift / alt / ctrl / caps-on etc. make up the meta/modifier keys.

Answer (score 1):

Use OnGlobalLayoutListener, it works perfectly for me.