# Change back to On-screen back button when soft keyboard is open in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

As you can see from the screenshot when i open the Keyboard the back button changes to a new action to close the Keyboard. Is there a way to disable this by code and show the On-screen back button instead?

I searched around but i couldn't find the answer.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please post screen shot so that we can get better idea about exactly what you need!

Comment: @Shrenik Can you please give me your email id i will mail you the screen shot.Here i cant be able add the image because of low reputation.

Comment: shrenik@vnnovate.com

Comment: @Shrenik I have mailed you the screenshot.

Comment: as far as i know we can't override that key.

Comment: @Shrenik so Is there any way to handle that key?

Comment: yes you need to check whether keyboard is showing or not during onBackPressed() method. May be that can help.

Comment: @Shrenik i have tried that also but i did not get a positive result from that way also.

Comment: mail me code snippet of onBackPressed() with keyboard show/hide check code. I will try that by self.

Comment: @Shrenik i have mailed you

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

you can override the back button on activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: #NaviRamyie This is for back button i am asking when the keyboard is open back button is changes into key down button  can we override that key or not?

Comment: I think he don't need this. The problem is different.

Comment: #Shrenik i have tried this also but still toast is not showing.i just want a callback response when the key board is going down  and at that time i have to show a tab..please help me in this

Comment: @ShubhamChauhan so you want to know if the keyboard is open or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/softkeyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android

Comment: #Shrenik Can you please give me your email id i will mail you the screen shot.Here i cant be able add the image because of low reputation.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by creating custom EditText and overriding dispatchKeyEventPreIme() there.

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {

        // your logic here

        return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event); // or return true if you don't want the keyboard to be hidden by system
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not worked for me..thank you for giving attention to my question