# Android - Control Keyboard show inside ChromeWebView

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Having a APP that loads inside an Activity a ChromeWebClient loads a webpage. This web page have's multiples forms / applications inside it. The funcionality that I want to control is to avoid the keyboard to show unless a variable is set up to be showed. (This variable only changes given a certain user actions). This is what I have test with no luck:

- Set up Listener to ChromeWebClient
- Set up listener to mainLayout
- Set up listener onConfigurationChanged
- Tryed this [SoftKeyboard open and close listener in an activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/softkeyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android)