# Get Android keyboard height when opening it, in Nativescript

Tags: android, angular, keyboard, height, nativescript

I have found several links that show how to get the height of the SoftKeyboard in Android, but my issue is that I don't know how access to it in Nativescript. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/softkeyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android) shows how to do it natively using Java but I would like to do that in Nativescript.
Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Following the link you provided in your question, it seems to me you want to get when the keyboard is showing not really the height. If i am correct their is a plugin for that in nativescript; https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-keyboardshowing.

It helps you to know if the keyboard is showing or hiding. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can see they are getting the height:

int keyboardHeight = heightDiff - contentViewTop;
onShowKeyboard(keyboardHeight);
I'm looking to trigger a function when the keyboard gets open as well as getting the height of it.. I actually tried that plugin a couple of weeks ago and it didn't work (the event functions never got triggered).

Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: The code located in the Github project may be a good start to get the height. Link: https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-keyboardshowing/blob/master/index.js . Thanks for the help