# Hiding ‘Bottom Navigation Bar’ whilst keyboard is present - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a small demo chat UI application. This application has a bottom navigation bar. I need the bottom navigation bar to hide when the keyboard appears.

[Here is an example of the chat UI](https://i.imgur.com/5jHtAeD.mp4)

As you can see when you click in the EditText element, the keyboard appears but the bottom navigation bar stays visible. I have tried methods such as [this measurement method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/18992807#18992807), but the UI elements flicker [like this](https://i.imgur.com/C2eNJBd.gifv).

Is there a proper way to hide the bottom navigation bar when the keyboard is visible?

**EDIT:**
In the below activity you can see where I set the keyboard listener to adjust the position of UI elements when the keyboard is determined as being visible.

This is my activity code, uses setKeyboardListener method from the above link and set it in onCreateView:

```
package uk.cal.codename.projectnedry.TeamChatFragment;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import uk.cal.codename.projectnedry.R;
import uk.cal.codename.projectnedry.TeamChatFragment.ListAdapter.TeamChatListAdapter;
import uk.demo.cal.genericmodelviewpresenter.GenericMvp.GenericMvpFragment;

import static android.view.View.GONE;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link TeamChatView.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link TeamChatView#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class TeamChatView extends GenericMvpFragment implements TeamChatContract.RequiredViewOps {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    @BindView(R.id.teamChatList)
    RecyclerView mTeamChatRecyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.teamChatSendButton)
    ImageButton mTeamChatSendButton;
    @BindView(R.id.messageTextInput)
    EditText mMessageTextInput;
    TeamChatListAdapter mTeamChatListAdapter;
    TeamChatListAdapter.ClickListener mTeamChatListClickListener;
    private ArrayList<String> mTestMessageList;

    public interface OnKeyboardVisibilityListener {
        void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible);
    }

    public final void setKeyboardListener(final OnKeyboardVisibilityListener listener) {
        final View activityRootView = ((ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            private boolean wasOpened;

            private final int DefaultKeyboardDP = 100;

            // From @nathanielwolf answer...  Lollipop includes button bar in the root. Add height of button bar (48dp) to maxDiff
            private final int EstimatedKeyboardDP = DefaultKeyboardDP + (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? 48 : 0);

            private final Rect r = new Rect();

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Convert the dp to pixels.
                int estimatedKeyboardHeight = (int) TypedValue
                        .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, EstimatedKeyboardDP, activityRootView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                // Conclude whether the keyboard is shown or not.
                activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                boolean isShown = heightDiff >= estimatedKeyboardHeight;

                if (isShown == wasOpened) {
                    Log.d("Keyboard state", "Ignoring global layout change...");
                    return;
                }

                wasOpened = isShown;
                listener.onVisibilityChanged(isShown);
            }
        });
    }

    public TeamChatView() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment TeamChatView.
     */
    public static TeamChatView newInstance() {
        TeamChatView fragment = new TeamChatView();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(TeamChatPresenter.class, TeamChatModel.class, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_chat_view, container, false);
        this.mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        mTestMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mTeamChatListAdapter = new TeamChatListAdapter(mTestMessageList);
        this.mTeamChatRecyclerView.setAdapter(this.mTeamChatListAdapter);
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        this.mTeamChatRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        this.mTeamChatSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!String.valueOf(mMessageTextInput.getText()).equals("")) {
                    getSpecificImpOfGenericPresenter().sendMessage(String.valueOf(mMessageTextInput.getText()));
                    mMessageTextInput.setText("");
                    mTeamChatRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mTestMessageList.size());
                }
            }
        });

        setKeyboardListener(new OnKeyboardVisibilityListener(){
            @Override
            public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
                RelativeLayout contentFrame = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.content_company_navigation);
                BottomBar lowerNavigationBar = (BottomBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
                if (visible) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    lowerNavigationBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                    contentFrame.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    mTeamChatRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mTestMessageList.size());
                } else {
                    contentFrame.setPadding(0, 0, 0, convertDpToPixel(60, getContext()));
                    mTeamChatRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mTestMessageList.size());
                    lowerNavigationBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * This method converts dp unit to equivalent pixels, depending on device density.
     *
     * @param dp A value in dp (density independent pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into pixels
     * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
     * @return A float value to represent px equivalent to dp depending on device density
     */
    public static int convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        int px = (int) (dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        return px;
    }

    public void addToTestMessageList(String str){
        this.mTestMessageList.add(str);
        this.mTeamChatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
       // getView().getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(test);
    }

    @Override
    public TeamChatPresenter getSpecificImpOfGenericPresenter() {
        return (TeamChatPresenter) this.mPresenter;
    }
}
```

This is my XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="uk.cal.codename.projectnedry.TeamChatFragment.TeamChatView">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_above="@+id/chatViewMessageEntryLayout"
        android:id="@+id/teamChatList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />    

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatViewMessageEntryLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/chatViewMessageEntrySeperator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#e3e3e8" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageTextInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chatViewMessageEntrySeperator"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/teamChatSendButton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Enter message"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="1000"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/teamChatSendButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#00B9EF"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post Your activity code here.

Comment: post your activity or fragment class along with xml

Comment: did you found any solution for this...i am also having the same problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ended up using the height measuring method that seems to be the standard way of soft keyboard detection which is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681196/5178283). However, I used [this library's](https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent) implementation of it, as it is still the same `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` method, implemented well, and allowed me to abstract the code out of my applications main codebase.

When this keyboard visibility listener is triggered, I then hide/show the bottom navigation bar (which I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843463/how-to-translate-a-view-but-keep-its-original-starting-position)).

Comment: That's the best answer since there might be an EditText (or subview containing EditText) in a recycler view. As a result you don't want to set adjustPan because in that case the keyboard might go over your content in recycler view.

Answer (score 129):

The easiest implementation, Add AndroidManifest.xml in

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

hopefully this helps someone out. Enjoy !

Comment: In this mode `ToolBar` is sliding out of the screen

Comment: When keyboard appears 'adjustPan' hides the Toolbar & 'adjustResize' shows overlapped Bottombar layout. Any solution?

Comment: Can also be added at the theme level in styles

Answer (score 34):

you just add this code in your manifest like this way..

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

this works for me.. happy coding

Comment: Can also be added at the theme level in styles

Answer (score 9):

Add this line in `onResume()` of your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

It is worked for me. Just try it once.

Answer (score 7):

Actively listen for the **Keyboard(IME)** open/close events and show/hide bottom navigation accordingly.

We can make use of the `WindowInsetsCompat` API which makes this job effortless.

**Step 1:** Make sure you have migrated to `AndroidX`

**Step 2:** In your `Fragment` inside `onCreateView` add the listener for Keyboard(IME) events

```kotlin
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView.rootView) { _, insets ->
 
   //This lambda block will be called, every time keyboard is opened or closed

    
    val imeVisible = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    if(imeVisible){ 
     //Now show-hide bottom navigation accordingly 
    } 

    insets
}
```

This is all you need

For more info on window insets, you can check out this in-depth [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animating-your-keyboard-fb776a8fb66d)

###### NOTE:

###### Earlier detecting Keyboard open/close events was not an easy task. Android Devs resorted to all types of hacks to accomplish this. But after decades of requests, prayers and rants Google finally came up with WindowInsets API. Thank you, Google

Comment: Seems like this listener adds additional padding above keyboard, how to avoid it?

Comment: Sorry mate, nothing of that happened to me. It's very unlikely that an event listener would add padding to your view boundaries. Maybe it's some other view, you can check your view hierarchy using Android Studio's Layout Inspector.

Comment: I guess it happened with my screen because of additional ```Spacer``` at the bottom and ```adjustResize``` flag in my activity, which lifted up a part of the spacer with the keyboard...

Answer (score 6):

Just add the attribute below to every activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
```

Comment: If you want to set a default mode for your application consider doing it in your theme using the attribute `<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan</item>`

Answer (score 4):

For API 21+:

Firstly, set "android:windowSoftInputMode" for the activity to "adjustResize" in AndroidManifest.xml

Secondly, in your acticity's onCreate method register the following listener:

```
window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, insets ->
    val insetsCompat = toWindowInsetsCompat(insets, view)
    val isImeVisible = insetsCompat.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    // below line, do the necessary stuff:
    dataBinding.bottomNavigation.visibility = if (isImeVisible) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    view.onApplyWindowInsets(insets)
}
```

Comment: using compat lib the first line is `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView)...` and the last one is `ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, insets)`

Answer (score 3):

```
 private boolean keyboardListenersAttached = false;
private ViewGroup rootLayout;


       @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);


    rootLayout = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.settings_layout);
    attachKeyboardListeners();

    return view;
}



    private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener keyboardLayoutListener = new 
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - 
        rootLayout.getHeight();
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            int contentViewTop = 
           getActivity().getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
            LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = 
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());
            Rect r = new Rect();
            rootLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int screenHeight = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight();

            // r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
            // if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
            int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;
            if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                onHideKeyboard();

                Intent intent = new Intent("KeyboardWillHide");
                broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
            } else {
                int keyboardHeight = heightDiff - contentViewTop;
                onShowKeyboard(keyboardHeight);

                Intent intent = new Intent("KeyboardWillShow");
                intent.putExtra("KeyboardHeight", keyboardHeight);
                broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }else {

        }
    }
};

protected void onShowKeyboard(int keyboardHeight) {
    System.out.println("keyboard is shown");
    dashboardActivity.bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dashboardActivity.fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
protected void onHideKeyboard() {
    System.out.println("keyboard is hide");
    dashboardActivity.bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    dashboardActivity.fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

protected void attachKeyboardListeners() {
    if (keyboardListenersAttached) {
        return;
    }

    rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(keyboardLayoutListener);
    keyboardListenersAttached = true;
}
```

in Manifest.xml file add

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity.DashboardActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

         />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the attribute : `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize""` in your manifest inside `activity` tag:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

**NB:** I suggest, You should use NestedScrollView as the parent layout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this, and it make my action bar disappear off screen along with the first 3 to 4 messages

Comment: Have you tried removing the measurement method ? You may give it a try commenting previous codes regarding this issue.

Comment: What is the point using NestedScrollView for a single RecycleView ? You may include a Parent Layout where you can add RecycleView and RelativeLayout (chatViewMessageEntryLayout) inside the NSV.

Comment: I removed the NSV and now just have the RecycleView. [This is what it looks like with adjustPan](http://i.imgur.com/BGfbJYD.mp4), as you can see the action bar vanishes and I only get half an EditTest visible.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Use adjustResize instead. You should wrap all of your views inside a scrollView otherwise keyboard won't have space to show.

Comment: Sadly I still get the flicker when the bottom nav bar appears/hides

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I am using DrawerLayout as a parent view with some layout content and A Navigation Bottom Bar. 
In Manifest file add "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" this TAG with Activity and this working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.OrderSceenWithOrder" 
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

That answer might be helpful for people still looking for solution.

[Bottom Navigation bar moves up with keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391743/bottom-navigation-bar-moves-up-with-keyboard)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30863689)

Answer (score -1):

Add this onResume() in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

That solution works for me and it also doesn't show overlapped bottom navbar
just add this line to your activity:

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"

Comment: The accepted answer explains why it's not sufficient to use "adjustResize|adjustPan" in some cases with an edit control.