# How to let BottomNavigationView stay down even when opening keyboard?

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I have a editText View, a RecyclerView and a Bottom Navigation View. 
When I tip on the EditText, then the keyboard opens and theRecyclerView is filled. But the BottomNavigationview is still on top of the now open keyboard, while my Recyclerview is on top of the bottomnavigation view. Now the recyclerview and edittext are overlaying while the keyboard is open. Is there any way to constrain it that the bottomnavigationview disappears while the keyboard is open?

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Abfahrtsmonitor">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Suche"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/Recycleview"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="441dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="511dp"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
```

This is how it looks right now: [image: How it shouldn't look]

Comment: Use **`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateHidden"`**

Comment: Thank you, it works

Comment: welcome you can  post that as an answer so it can help other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding ‘Bottom Navigation Bar’ whilst keyboard is present - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115510/hiding-bottom-navigation-bar-whilst-keyboard-is-present-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do below in your activity tag defined in Manifest.

```
<activity
      android:name=".YourActivity"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add the following **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** to your activity that holds the *BottomNavigationView*

```
   <application
        android:name=".ExampleApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
</application>
```

This solution had worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `android:windowSoftInputMode` from `manifest` or you can set it as `stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing`.