# Bottom Navigation element shifts position when typing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bottomnav

I'm facing a weird issue where my bottom navigation jumps to be above the keyboard when typing. This is only done when I'm setting a view that is next to the edittext, as shown in the screenshot, from 'View.GONE' to 'View.VISIBLE'

[image]

Comment: did you try to add dis on your manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` ?

Comment: add your xml file too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding ‘Bottom Navigation Bar’ whilst keyboard is present - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115510/hiding-bottom-navigation-bar-whilst-keyboard-is-present-android)

Comment: This is an Epic one . use the accepted answer from above link .

Answer (score 0):

Give this tag in Manifest file ***android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"***

```
<activity
            android:name=".Youractivity"
            ...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```