# ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener() changes background of system navigation bar

Tags: android, windowinsets

App normally has this navigation bar:

[image]

But when I add `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener()`

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView) { _, insets ->
    binding.showingKeyboard = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
}
```

or

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView) { _, insets ->
    binding.showingKeyboard = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    insets
}
```

it becomes like this

[image]

Why does it happen? I don't want this method to change anything. I just want to use it to detect if the virtual keyboard is visible or not (there are no other good methods to do it)

Comment: I have answered this in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73848116/3187176

Comment: Just return `ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, insets)` instead of `insets` >> don't forget to set the 1st parameter to `v`

Answer (score 1):

Call `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` on root view of your layout, not on `window.decorView`