# setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener - statusBar color problem

Tags: android, windowinsets

Why when I use

> setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener

statusBar color disappears?

```
 fun isKeyboardVisible(view: View) {
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { view, windowInsets ->
        val isKeyboardVisible = windowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
        if (isKeyboardVisible) Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        windowInsets
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @dalemncy yes, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73848116/3187176

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view)`, use `window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener`, returning `view.onApplyWindowInsets(insets)` like so:

```
 window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, insets ->

            //do your thing here

            view.onApplyWindowInsets(insets)
 }
```

And that is it.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: But it's required     
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)