# How to detect in android that soft-keyboard show/hide in any other Application?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, broadcast, receiver

I want to receive the broadcast in my android app whenever soft-keyboard show/hide from any other application.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Please show us what you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. If the application you're writing about doesn't expose such events, then you're out of luck. Besides, soft keyboard is a separate app and it doesn't have events for showing or hiding it. That's why even if you would only like to detect these events in your app, you would need hacks to handle that. Here you can find an idea: [SoftKeyboard open and close listener in an activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/softkeyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android)