# Searchview clear focus on hide keyboard

Tags: java, android, searchview

The user presses the hide keyboard button or the back button.
So I need to clear focus on the SearchView when the user is hiding the keyboard.

I tried this but it's not working. focus remains when the user hides the keyboard.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                app.requests.getApi().search(newText).enqueue(SearchFragment.this);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and this:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    app.functions.logWrite("has focus to searchview");
                } else {
                    //code
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so try this it needs the use of a library unfortunately but it makes it easier.

In your **build.gradle**: add this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:3.0.0-RC2'
}
```

Register for the keyboard events using [KeyboardVisibilityEvent library](https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent) like this in the fragment/class where `SearchView` is declared:

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(
    getActivity(),
    new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
            if (!isOpen) {
               View focusedView = getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
               if (focusedView != null && focusedView instanceof SearchView) { // does SearchView have focus?
                    searchView.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

`searchView.clearFocus();` works on the assumption you have another focusable view in the hierarchy, if not add this to your fragments layout:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Alternatively simply call `focus();` on any other view element you want to receive focus.

Comment: sorry bro it's not working. when i press down on keyboard.

Comment: Okay but it's working when the searchview is closed via the back button ? And you saw my updated answer right ?

Comment: Also it wouldn't make sense to dismiss the search when the keyboard is hidden only if the back buttons are pressed..  I mean imagine the user searches then dismissed the keyboard to see the results in full screen, now the search view is closed not sure that makes sense

Comment: So it's not working only when the keyboard is hidden? Or what ? Sorry just need more clarification

Comment: yes it's not working only when i press down on keyboard.

Comment: Did you see my other comment does it really make sense to hide the searchview when the keyboard is simply hidden? I don't think so...

Comment: yes it makes sense.. on NETFLIX it's workking.When i press down on keyboard netlifx's searcView automaticly clear focus

Comment: @Mkurbanov see my updated answer its a bit long but that should get you what you need i.e. removing focus from the searchview when the keyboard is hidden

Comment: Updated answer to check `focusedView != null` as this may cause an exception if we dont

Comment: thanks man. it's working. But i tried this without EventBus. And it to 
 working. Why you using EventBus i don't know. can you explain? and thx)

Comment: Awesome. You don't need eventbus but I don't know how your app was setup, eventbus just makes life easier to communicate between activities and fragments and vice versa. So for example if you registered the keyboard listener in your activity but the searchview existed in your fragment eventbus makes it easier to communicate to the fragment about the event that's registered in your activity without using intents or localbroadcasts

Comment: But maybe it was overkill lol ill add an update.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for handling back button clicks for `SearchView`, by Overriding `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            ANY_VIEW_IN_YOUR_LAYOUT.requestFocus();
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: This will only work if the back button is pressed not the down arrow which simply hides the keyboard

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25216749/9652621) question may help you...