# Keyboard listener in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a kotlin android app. How do I track if a soft keyboard is opened? Basically a keyboard listener. **Note that this doesn't work with kotlin - [Soft keyboard open and close listener in an activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/soft-keyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android)**. I need the same functionality but with kotlin.

Comment: "I need the same functionality but with kotlin" -- then translate the code to Kotlin. For example, if you are using Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA as IDEs, they have tools built in to help convert Java code to Kotlin.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, but there are some modules that are not supported in kotlin.