# Is there an android keyboard listener?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am an Android developer. During development, I wondered if there was a listener on the soft keyboard. Is there something like a `listener` or `observer` that can detect when the keyboard goes up and down?

In addition, if you look at the bottom of the mobile with the keyboard raised, the navigation button has a [keyboard down button] except for the [home button] and [multi-task button]. Can you put your code in the `setOnClickListener` for this [keyboard down button]? For example, when the keyboard down button is pressed, the Toast is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the accepted answer here, "You can use a layout listener to see if the root layout of your activity is resized by the keyboard.": [Soft keyboard open and close listener in an activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/soft-keyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android)