# Track the opening of the keyboard in the ionic angular mobile application(Android)

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to track the opening of the keyboard in order to perform some actions when opening it.

I used various methods for example:

```
Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', info => {

});
Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', info => {

});
```

But for some reason, keyboardWillShow and keyboardDidShow are triggered not when the keyboard is opened, but when it is closed or when you start typing something into the input.
Why can there be such a strange behavior?

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/soft-keyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the Ionic doc for angular, here is the doc of the Keyboard lyfecicle : https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/keyboard

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(private platform: Platform) {
 this.platform.keyboardDidShow.subscribe(ev => {
 const { keyboardHeight } = ev;
 // Do something with the keyboard height such as translating an input above 
the keyboard.
 });

this.platform.keyboardDidHide.subscribe(() => {
// Move input back to original location
 });
}
```

Comment: This method has the same behavior as described in the problem above. I want to react specifically to the opening of the keyboard