# How to know height of softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the height of virtual keyboard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009487/get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-in-android)

If I click on `EditText` I am getting soft keyboard. I need to know `height` of default soft keyboard. I didnt find any standard method to get height of soft keyboard. How to know `height` of soft keyboard on Android?

Comment: The answer to this question seems to be covered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009487/get-height-of-virtualkeyboard-in-android