# Is there any way in Android to get the height of virtual keyboard of device

Tags: android, sdk

Is there any way in Android to get the height of the virtual keyboard displayed on the device in run time? Actually I want to show a text box above the keyboard.

Comment: similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009487/get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-in-android) :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes you can, with the help of Viewtree Observer and global layout listener, just try below mentioned steps

1. Get the root view of your layout
2. get the Viewtree observer for this root, and add a global layout listener on top of this.

now whenever soft keyboard is displayed android will re-size your screen and you will receive  call on your listener. That's it only thing you now need to do is calculate difference between height which your root view has after re-size and original size. If difference is more then 150 consider this as a keyboard has been inflated.

Below is a sample code

```
root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
     public void onGlobalLayout(){
           int heightDiff = root.getRootView().getHeight()- root.getHeight();
           // IF height diff is more then 150, consider keyboard as visible.  
        }
  });
```

Regards,
Techfist

Comment: i think this only works when android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: this just gets whether or not the keyboard is shown, but it doesn't give you the height of the keyboard.

Comment: Heightdiff will give you, the amount of space keyboard is taken up.

Comment: Is this height in pixels or dp?

Comment: 150px is not enough for xxhdpi devices like the Nexus 5. Its better to convert this absolute pixel value from a dp value and use that instead. I use `120dp` and that works well for Nexus 7 (xhdpi) and Nexus 5 (xxhdpi). Your experiences may vary, though...

Comment: And `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ` should be put in the AndroidMainfest's Activity attribution where your soft keyboard has been used.

Comment: Doesn't work, some devices this code still > 0 when keyboard is not opened
            int heightDiff = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - rootLayout.getHeight();

Comment: Just record the height before adding the observer. Then compare the value when it fires to the original value. If it is more, the keyboard is open and you can use heightDiff; if the same, the keyboard is closed. 150 is not a good guide, mine was 206 before adding the observer.

Answer (score 57):

To solve this I have written a keyboardHeightProvider which can calculate the height of a floating soft keyboard. The Activity can be set to adjustNone or adjustPan in the AndroidManifest.xml.

https://github.com/siebeprojects/samples-keyboardheight

Siebe

Comment: This code doesnt work on phone with notch i am getting the wrong height...

Comment: I thought this was working fine for so long, but then I noticed the height is wrong on Chromebooks in tablet mode :'(

Comment: @Sniper, for phone with notch, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52063876/668963).

Comment: Hi just let other guys here know that this type of solution will not work always. There are lots of reasons this could not  work, due to OS-specific API, spit mode, window mode, immersive mode or notch etc

Answer (score 49):

I tried many suggested methods for this, but none seemed to work for Android SDL. I think this is either because the SDL display is "full screen" or that it sits within an "AbsoluteLayout" and therefore the height of the "View" never actually changes. This method worked for me:

[Getting the dimensions of the soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534365/getting-the-dimensions-of-the-soft-keyboard)

```
Window mRootWindow = getWindow();
View mRootView = mRootWindow.getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
mRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout(){
        Rect r = new Rect();
        View view = mRootWindow.getDecorView();
        view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        // r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom
    }
    });
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. @Dave Lawrence you should mention in the answer that it the Rect's height doesn't take into account the status bar.

Comment: How to calculate the height of keyboard from this method?

Comment: In my case : int heightDiff = mRootView.getHeight() - r.bottom;  worked fine

Answer (score 17):

### 2022 solution

With a new [Window insets](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui) api it is pretty simple:

```
WindowInsetsCompat insets = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(activity.getWindow().getDecorView());
//Enjoy your keyboard height
int keyboardHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom;
```

You can also easily listen for keyboard show/hide events:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(activity.getWindow().getDecorView(), (v, insets) -> {
   boolean isKeyboardVisible = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime());
   int keyboardHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom;
   
   //Do your job here

   return insets;
});
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/sw-keyboard).

Comment: This is just perfect, except that it makes the Status Bar color disappear and turn white for some reason. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: On the top of Peter comment, the retrieved keyboard height also incorrect. From my naked eye, the returned value seems to be (actual keyboard height + status bar height)

Comment: @Peter I think you just need to update a few xml settings when using the new WindowInsets API. [See this](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge)

Comment: @CheokYanCheng This setting affects the calculations: `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`. Irregardless, you can validate the keyboard height by getting the combined height of the top and bottom insets:
`Insets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()).bottom`. There's other options for `WindowInsets.Type` too.

Comment: Nice work! But now a layout occupies whole height (bottom elements are behind navigation bar). You should customize insets before `return insets;`.

Comment: See also https://www.kodeco.com/18393648-window-insets-and-keyboard-animations-tutorial-for-android-11 for API 30+.

Comment: Listener doesn't fire properly on Android API 29. Need a backwards compatible solution.

Answer (score 9):

This method works with `adjustNothing` or any `windowSoftInputMode` on your activity.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"/>
```

Using a `PopupWindow`, you can have separate "keyboard behaviour" for it, and it will notify you what the size of the keyboard is. The PopupWindow has the height of the screen, but 0px width, so you won't see it, it won't affect your activity, but will provide you with the information you need.

Create a class called `KeyboardHeightProvider` and add the following code:

```
public class KeyboardHeightProvider extends PopupWindow {
    public KeyboardHeightProvider(Context context, WindowManager windowManager, View parentView, KeyboardHeightListener listener) {
        super(context);

        LinearLayout popupView = new LinearLayout(context);
        popupView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        popupView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            Rect rect = new Rect();
            popupView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

            int keyboardHeight = metrics.heightPixels - (rect.bottom - rect.top);
            int resourceID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceID > 0) {
                keyboardHeight -= context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceID);
            }
            if (keyboardHeight < 100) {
                keyboardHeight = 0;
            }
            boolean isLandscape = metrics.widthPixels > metrics.heightPixels;
            boolean keyboardOpen = keyboardHeight > 0;
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onKeyboardHeightChanged(keyboardHeight, keyboardOpen, isLandscape);
            }
        });

        setContentView(popupView);

        setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
        setWidth(0);
        setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

        parentView.post(() -> showAtLocation(parentView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0));
    }

    public interface KeyboardHeightListener {
        void onKeyboardHeightChanged(int keyboardHeight, boolean keyboardOpen, boolean isLandscape);
    }
}
```

Notice how the PopupWindow has its own `setSoftInputMode(...)`, so it doesn't matter what you set your activity to, the PopupWindow will still be affected by the keyboard opening or closing and will provide the parent activity of the height. If the height is `>= 100` you can assume the keyboard is open.

To use it, simply instantiate it in your Activity's `onCreate(...)` method after `setContentView(...)`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    LinearLayout llRoot = findViewById(R.id.llRoot); //The root layout (Linear, Relative, Contraint, etc...)

    new KeyboardHeightProvider(this, getWindowManager(), llRoot, new KeyboardHeightProvider.KeyboardHeightListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyboardHeightChanged(int keyboardHeight, boolean keyboardOpen, boolean isLandscape) {
            Log.i("keyboard listener", "keyboardHeight: " + keyboardHeight + " keyboardOpen: " + keyboardOpen + " isLandscape: " + isLandscape);

            //Do what you want or have to with the parameters..
        }
    });

    //...
}
```

Comment: I had extra space above the keyboard, subtract `resourceID` fixed the problem.

Comment: This works but I'm getting a memory leak warning when rotating the device. I was able to remove that by calling `dismiss` on the `PopupWindow` in `onPause` of my `Activity`

Answer (score 8):

put the text box as parent bottom.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and in the manifest file make the soft input `adjustresize`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

then the text box will move up when the keyboard appears.

Answer (score 7):

You can't tell.  No, really: you simply can't tell.

The keyboard does not need to be any particular shape. It does not have to be placed at the bottom of the screen ([many](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/fixedbyvonnie-galaxy-s4-floating-keyboard.png) of the [most popular](http://www.mobilevillage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/SwiftKey-floating-keyboard.jpg) options [are not](http://octoba.jp/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/com.justsystems.atokmobile.service.png)), it does not have to keep its current size when you change text fields (almost none do depending on the flags). It does not even have to be [rectangular](https://lh5.ggpht.com/LrJXz8w0yS7xfWocU2dgpeRm63tB-2Y3-JdBZ7tkRPxSoziLqEckAPnfYa5kiZwL44o=h900). It may also just take over the [entire screen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#FullscreenMode).

(copy of my answer on a similar question, [Getting the dimensions of the soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534365/getting-the-dimensions-of-the-soft-keyboard) )

Answer (score 2):

As the navigation bars, keyboard, etc are added to the window, you can measure these insets to check if the keyboard is open or not.  With Android R, you can measure the keyboard directly, but you can fall back to calculating the keyboard size from the insets for prior versions.

This works on Lollipop and up.

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
               .setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
             
                   @Override
                   public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
                       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                           mKeyboardShowing =
                                   insets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime()).bottom > 0;
                           if (mKeyboardShowing) {
                               setKeyboardHeight(
                                       insets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime()).bottom -
                                       insets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()).bottom);
                           }
                       } else {
                           mKeyboardShowing = getNavigationBarHeight() !=
                                              insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
                           if (mKeyboardShowing) {
                               setKeyboardHeight(insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() -
                                                 getNavigationBarHeight());
                           }
                       }
                       return v.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
                   }

                   public int getNavigationBarHeight() {
                       boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(MainActivity.this)
                                                             .hasPermanentMenuKey();
                       int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height",
                                                                     "dimen",
                                                                     "android");
                       if (resourceId > 0 && !hasMenuKey) {
                           return getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                       }
                       return 0;
                   }
               });
```

Comment: `navigation_bar_height ` is not exposed as public method and is not guaranteed to work in all types of devices

Answer (score 1):

My solution is the combination of all above solutions. This solution is also hacky but solve the problem (atleast for me).

1. I have places on temporary view with transparent background at the bottom of the screen.
2. I have added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` flag in activity tag in manifest like @bill suggests.
3. Now main story is in `onGlobalLayout()`. There i calculate the difference between the y axis of temp view and height of root view

   ```
   final View view = findViewById(R.id.base);

   view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

       @Override
       public void onGlobalLayout() {

           int rootViewHeight = view.getRootView().getHeight();
           View tv = findViewById(R.id.temp_view);
           int location[] = new int[2];
           tv.getLocationOnScreen(location);
           int height = (int) (location[1] + tv.getMeasuredHeight());
           deff = rootViewHeight - height;
           // deff is the height of soft keyboard

       }
   });
   ```

But anyways to solve the problem of @zeeshan0026 only a single flag in manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` is enough.

Comment: If we use adjustNothing flag then the view will not render again when keyboard open so apparently onGlobalLayout should not call and we will not able to get the change in size. Though i did not try by myself but this is what expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this to get keyboard height programmatically in android and tested it, please try this once:

```
myLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    parent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                    int screenHeight = parent.getRootView().getHeight();
                    int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom - r.top);
                    Log.d("Keyboard Size", "Size: " + heightDifference);

                    //boolean visible = heightDiff > screenHeight / 3;
                }
            });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do not forget removing the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` inside the callback.

Comment: I use the same approach, but still some devices seem to have issue. One galaxy s9  with custom keyboard seem to be failing on this.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to get the height of soft/virtual keyboard. I cannot say this works on all devices, but I tried on some devices both real and emulator devices and it works. I tried on devices from Android API 16 to 29. It is a little bit tricky. Here is my analysis.

First, I tried to subtract between the height of the screen and height of visible frame on top of soft/virtual keyboard by using function of `getHeightDifference()` such as below. I found that at the first time the layout is created, right before the keyboard open on EditText's focus, the difference height will depend on Android System Navigation Bar, either the Navigation Bar is shown inside the device screen or not. So, the value of `heightDifference` will be 0 if the Nav Bar outside the screen or greater than 0 if it is inside the screen. I'm using a variable of `systemNavigationBarHeight` with Integer object (instead of using primitive `int` data) to save the first value of that height difference with only one initialization, which I assume that is the height of Nav Bar.

And then in next code block, I check if next height difference is greater than the height of actual Navigation Bar in Android system (or 100 is default just in case if there is no Navigation Bar in Android system), then I subtract again with the value of `systemNavigationBarHeight` to get the real height of soft/virtual keyboard.

Hope this will help on someone who look up another answer.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    private Integer systemNavigationBarHeight = null;
                        
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        int heightDifference = getHeightDifference();
                        if (heightDifference > 0) {
                            if (systemNavigationBarHeight == null) {
                                /* Get layout height when the layout was created at first time */
                                systemNavigationBarHeight = heightDifference;
                            }
                        } else {
                            systemNavigationBarHeight = 0;
                        }

                        if (heightDifference > getDefaultNavigationBarHeight()) {
                            /* Keyboard opened */
                            int keyBoardHeight = heightDifference - systemNavigationBarHeight;
                        } else {
                            /* Keyboard closed */
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
    
    private int getHeightDifference() {
        Point screenSize = new Point();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(screenSize);
        } else {
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(screenSize);
        }

        Rect rect = new Rect();
        rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
        return screenSize.y - rect.bottom;
    }
    
    private int getDefaultNavigationBarHeight() {
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            return getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**2023 solution**

If you use `androidx.compose.foundation` you can get ime visibility and height (bottom) as simple as:

```
val imeVisible = WindowInsets.isImeVisible
val bottom = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(LocalDensity.current)
```

To setup, you can  [follow this video](https://youtu.be/mlL6H-s0nF0?t=101) or:

1. On your acitivty `onCreate` method:

   ```
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
   ```
2. *AndroidManifest.xml*

   `<application ... android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">`
3. *Themes.xml*

   `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

   `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Answer (score 0):

For API >= 30.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private fun getKeyboardHeight(view: View): Int {
    return view.rootWindowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom -
            getNavBarHeight(view)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private fun getNavBarHeight(view: View): Int {
    return view.rootWindowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars()).bottom
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private fun isKeyboardVisible(insets: WindowInsets): Boolean {
    return insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
}
```

See also https://www.kodeco.com/18393648-window-insets-and-keyboard-animations-tutorial-for-android-11.

Answer (score -1):

A solution that I've found excellent for me, was to store a global `bottom` value, then to add a TreeView Observer and compare the new bottom value with the stored one. Using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

```
private var bottom: Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    val rect = Rect()
    this.window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
    this.bottom = rect.bottom

    this.window.decorView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        
        val newRect = Rect()
        this.window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(newRect)
        
        // the answer
        val keyboardHeight = this.bottom - newRect.bottom

        // also
        if (newRect.bottom < this.bottom) {
            //keyboard is open
            
        } else {
            //keyboard is hide
            
        }
    }
}
```