# How do I get the soft keyboard identifier in android

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

I'd like to get the soft keyboard identifier in android for the purpose of determining the keyboard height. The end goal is that I want to reposition a view on the screen vertically to be centered between the top of the keyboard and the bottom of the status bar. I can get the status bar height with the following code:

```
int statusBarHeight = 0;
int resourceId = Resources.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if(resourceId > 0) {
    statusBarHeight = Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
```

Can I get the height of the soft keyboard in a similar way?
I am using Xamarin because I am sharing a backend between my iOS app and Android app, but the code seems to be pretty similar for Android. I am also creating my views entirely in code which is what I prefer; so my question is how can I get the keyboard height in code in order to position a view in code?

Comment: May I suggest Viewtree Observer Global layout listener. You can use simple maths to get the height of keyboard from this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using **ViewTree Observer**. With the root view, you'll be able to calculate the new size when the keyboard appears.

The question below may help you, as it helped me:

[Is there any way in android to get the height of virtual keyboard of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device)

Comment: rootView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
     Rect r = new Rect();
     layout.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
     int screenH = layout.RootView.Height;
     int heightDiff = screenH - (r.Bottom - r.Top);
     if(heightDiff > screenH / 4) {
          keyboardHeight = heightDiff;
     }
};