# Android VirtualKeyboard Height in FullScreen

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, android-fullscreen

I know there is a way to get the keyboard height, but it seems to not work in fullscreen mode.

I would like to know how to get the virtual keyboard height **in fullscreen**.

*I'm not using android UI, I'm using an OpenGL context inside an intent.*

thanks you please.

Comment: follow the link for same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device. solved

Comment: it is not for FullScreen.

Comment: The fullScreen mode implementation is different from normal case. In fullscreen mode the EditText is also part of InputMethod window so the whole screen is covered IME(keyboard + EditText). 
Can you provide more information about what you want to do with keyboard height?

Comment: @dinesh I'm making a user interface in opengl, for my opengl game in android. I need the keyboard height to make a textField. I need to fit the writing text at the top of the keyboard.