# Get Android softkeyboard height _without_ "adjustResize"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest

I have an animation between two fragments. The second fragment will bring up a keyboard. As the keyboard will cover parts of the screen, I manually need to but a spacer view in there to adjust my view. Using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` will result in my transition-animation to be super laggy. Using `adjustNothing` on the other hand will make it smooth.

So is there any way to get the keyboard height **without** using `adjustResize`?

**EDIT:**
My question is different to f.e. [Is there any way in android to get the height of virtual keyboard of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device) as I can't add `adjustResize`

Comment: You can use the solution from this answer, using a ViewTreeObserver: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19494006/4850160 It's more manual work, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device

Comment: THis is right answer for this
https://github.com/siebeprojects/samples-keyboardheight

Comment: I set the activity to adjustNothing and use above library which is samples-keyboardheight. It works greatly!