# How I can type on editbox while spinner item list remain open for showing filtered records

Tags: android

I am using android Spinner with custom adapter and custom list layout, i want to write in editbox with spinner item list remain open for showing filterd records , my problem is item list of spinner is to long and its cover softkey board, fisr of all i want to reduce the  length of item list in spinner and second it should remain open while typing in another edit box .

Check this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvcmm.png)

my code is below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/accountname_combo"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/accountnameid_combo"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



public class adapter_AccountList extends ArrayAdapter<coa> implements Filterable {


    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<coa> data = null;
    LayoutInflater flater;

    public adapter_AccountList(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<coa> Accounts) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, Accounts);

        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = Accounts;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        viewHolder holder ;
        coa rowItem = getItem(position);

        if (row == null) {
            holder = new viewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder.accountname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.accountname_combo);
            holder.accountid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.accountnameid_combo);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (viewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.accountname.setText(rowItem.getAccountName());
        holder.accountid.setText(rowItem.getID());
        return row;

    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }


    static class viewHolder {
        TextView accountname;
        TextView accountid;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part of the question the easiest solution would be to use a **CardView** instead of the spinner and change the visibility on clicking the arrow

```
cardView.setVisivility(View.VISIBLE);
cardView.setVisivility(View.GONE);
```

The keyboard is a little tricky:
Android doesn't allow you to detect if the soft input is open or not, but there is a workaround.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device)

When you get the height of the keyboard just make you `cardView` smaller accordingly: the list will adjust itself.

```
cardView.setHeight(cardview.getHeight() - keyboardHeight);
```

Also don't forget to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in  tag in your Manifest file.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hey for this you have to used the Autocomplete Text view widget of Android.
Can can refer this link.[Check this link of Autocomplete Text view](http://androidexample.com/Show_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=105)