# Full-screen AlertDialog has janky animation when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-windowmanager

Watch the video here to see the problem: https://streamable.com/s0yhrm

Or see it here on a faster device: https://streamable.com/4sshdn

I have an AlertDialog that I've set up to take all the vertical space. The problem is that when the keyboard appears, I get a nasty animation as the AlertDialog resizes to fit above the keyboard. Is there some way to prevent this from happening? Ideally, it should measure the available space above the keyboard before the AlertDialog ever displays.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/enter_address_alert_dialog_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Delivery address"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/network_error_imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cloud_off_36dp"
        app:tint="@color/colorError"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/title_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/title_textView"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_textView"
        android:background="@drawable/autocomplete_list_item_background"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/address_editText"
                style="@style/MyEditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Street address"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/address_alert_dialog_text_size" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/clear_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_24dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/enter_address_unit_number_alert_dialog_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:hint="Unit #"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textCapWords|text"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/address_alert_dialog_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/map_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_LinearLayout">

        <!--Single parent to ScrollView-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/no_store_address_enter_address_alert_dialog_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/address_autocomplete_margin_above_empty_view"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/address_alert_dialog_no_store_address_text_size"
                android:text="You haven't entered a store address. Without this, the app can't locate delivery addresses or calculate driving distances. To fix this, go to Settings and use the 'Store addresses' option."
                android:textColor="#F00"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/enter_address_alert_dialog_empty_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/address_autocomplete_margin_above_empty_view"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Start typing an address above and matching results will show up here"
                android:textSize="@dimen/address_alert_dialog_text_size"
                app:drawableTint="@color/colorAutocompleteEmptyViewIcon"
                app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_search_white_28dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/enter_address_alert_dialog_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/map_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="-3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/map_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_image_button_ripple"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="MAP"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAlertDialogButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/submit_button"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_image_button_ripple"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAlertDialogButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_image_button_ripple"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAlertDialogButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_text_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your links giving me error . can you check

Comment: Here's a Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDCGRqeMxGE&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this in a satisfactory manner by expanding the AlertDialog's height only once the user starts typing. See video here: https://streamable.com/oj3fbv

```
       addressEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String inputText = s.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                if (inputText.length() > 0) {
                    if (inputText.length() == 1) {
                    autocompleteListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams listViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                        listViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, topLinearLayout.getId());
                        listViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, mapButton.getId());
                        listViewParams.leftMargin = dpToPx(8);
                        listViewParams.rightMargin = dpToPx(8);
                        listViewParams.topMargin = dpToPx(4);
                        listViewParams.bottomMargin = dpToPx(4);
                        autocompleteListView.setLayoutParams(listViewParams);

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mapButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        mapButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                        mapButton.setLayoutParams(mapButtonParams);
                    }

                    clearButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if (inputText.length() > 1 && storeAddressEntered) {
                        alertDialogEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        scrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                alertDialogAdapter.getFilter().filter(inputText);
            }
        });
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/enter_address_alert_dialog_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Delivery address"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/network_error_imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cloud_off_36dp"
        app:tint="@color/colorError"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/title_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/title_textView"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_textView"
        android:background="@drawable/autocomplete_list_item_background"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/address_editText"
                style="@style/MyEditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Street address"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/address_alert_dialog_text_size" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/clear_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_24dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/enter_address_unit_number_alert_dialog_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:hint="Unit #"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textCapWords|text"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/address_alert_dialog_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_LinearLayout">

        <!--Single parent to ScrollView-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/no_store_address_enter_address_alert_dialog_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/address_autocomplete_margin_above_empty_view"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/address_alert_dialog_no_store_address_text_size"
                android:text="You haven't entered a store address. Without this, the app can't locate delivery addresses or calculate driving distances. To fix this, go to Settings and use the 'Store addresses' option."
                android:textColor="#F00"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/enter_address_alert_dialog_empty_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Start typing an address above and matching results will show up here"
                android:textSize="@dimen/address_alert_dialog_text_size"
                app:drawableTint="@color/colorAutocompleteEmptyViewIcon"
                app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_search_white_28dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/enter_address_alert_dialog_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="-3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/map_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_image_button_ripple"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="MAP"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAlertDialogButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/map_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/submit_button"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_image_button_ripple"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAlertDialogButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/map_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_image_button_ripple"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAlertDialogButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_text_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no "default" workaround for your problem. your `Dialog` appears at first, then `EditText` is drawn, it requests focus and then keyboard shows - `Dialog` is already drawn (full screen), so it shrinks

maybe you can try to force show keyboard BEFORE `Dialog` appears

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
    toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

then show your `Dialog` (maybe with some few milisec delay?) and call `editText.requestFocus()` for "connecting" keyboard to freshly shown `EditText` (there is a change is will be done automatically, as `EditText` may request focus when inflated)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it previously and GBoard actually adds a row of buttons when an EditText has focus. So the AlertDialog ends up resizing again anyways.

Comment: :/ these buttons are probably some suggestions for `EditText` typing, above line is just forcing keyboard to be shown, if it detect that it isn't "connected" to any `EditText` then there is no buttons/suggestions at all. maybe another workaround - just create dummy, not attached to layout `EditText et = new EditText(ctx);` and then `dummyEditText.requestFocus();` for showing keyboard with buttons (connected to this dummy `EditText`). then when `Dialog` appears switch focus to final `EditText`, which belongs to `Dialog`

Comment: That's a nice one I hadn't thought of. I think ultimately I might just end up initially showing a shorter dialog, and then when the user starts typing expand it to its full height (maybe animate the expansion even). That way I avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: this still will give you a blink/resize sadly... yet another suggestion: reconcile with this behavior at first `Dialog` open, but [measure keyboard size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device) and set proper `Dialog` height for second and further opens. still remember that user may change size of keyboard or even whole keyboard app, so measuring logic should be done always when `Dialog`/keyboard appears (then compared with height stored locally)

Comment: See the answer I just added. I ended up going a different way, but I appreciate your help!