# How to use WindowInsetsCompat correctly to listen to keyboard height change in Activity?

Tags: android, windowinsets, android-window

It seems like the official way, to listen to keyboard height change, is to use `WindowInsetsCompat` based on https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/sw-keyboard

( An unofficial is to have an invisible `PopupWindow` to monitor keyboard height change. But, this is not a reliable method due to today numerous devices with different notch, split screen mode, ... - [Is there any way in Android to get the height of virtual keyboard of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device) )

We try to experiment, to see how we can monitor keyboard height correctly.

### Before applying `WindowInsetsCompat`

[image]

---

After applying `WindowInsetsCompat` with the following code.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View keyboardView = findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), (v, insets) -> {
            boolean imeVisible = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime());
            int imeHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom;

            android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "imeVisible = " + imeVisible + ", imeHeight = " + imeHeight);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = keyboardView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = imeHeight;
            keyboardView.setLayoutParams(params);

            return insets;
        });
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_linear_layout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#22000000">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_button_0"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_alarm_on_24" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff0000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Outcome of `WindowInsetsCompat` (When keyboard is not visible)

[image]

---

### Outcome of `WindowInsetsCompat` (When keyboard is visible)

[image]

---

Here's the observation

1. For testing purpose, we do not use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.
2. After applying `WindowInsetsCompat`, the top status bar and bottom soft key background become white!
3. The returned keyboard's height isn't correct. (If the keyboard height is correct, we shouldn't see the red color `keyboardView`, because we have set the height of `keyboardView` to be same as keyboard's height)

---

May I know, when using `WindowInsetsCompat` to monitor keyboard's height, how can I

1. Avoid status bar and bottom soft key background from becoming white?
2. Get the correct keyboard's height?

The following is the workable demo - https://github.com/yccheok/wediary-sandbox/tree/master/keyboard-bottom-sheet-integration

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Avoid status bar and bottom soft key background from becoming white?

This requires to readjust the insets to `WindowInsetsCompat`by returning `ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, insets)` instead of `insets` from the `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener()` callback.

> Get the correct keyboard's height?

The insets are calculated based on the far ends of the screen (it makes sense as they're named as **window insets**, not the activity insets).

So, in case of the ime/keyboard we are interested in the bottom inset which equals to the top edge of the keyboard to the bottom edge of the screen; this includes the system navigation insets (i.e., the height of the navigation bar).

The red view is shown because it's drawn on top of the navigation bar; it doesn't take the navBar height into consideration.

So, to get the exact height of the keyboard, we need to subtract the **navBarHeight** from the **imeHeight**:

```
int imeHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom 
                - insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).bottom;
```

Please notice the quote of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsCompat#getInsets(int)) about ime insets:

> When running on devices with API Level 29 and before, the returned
> insets are an approximation based on the information available. This
> is especially true for the IME type, which currently only works when
> running on devices with SDK **level 23 and above**.