# How can I get the height of keyboard of current input method without showing it?

Tags: android, view, keyboard

It seems that it cannot be achieved through `InputMethodManager`, but there seems to be a method `getHeight()` in `Keyboard`.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I am not writing my own input method.

Comment: Are you the one writing the input method?

Comment: @CommonsWare I hope to create a view of the same height of the keyboard.

Comment: getHeight in keyboard won't work for 2 reasons.  First is if you aren't writing the keyboard, you have no reference to call it on.  Secondly, none of the major keyboards actually use that API, its too limiting.

Comment: That's impossible because we can do **anything** before IME window is shown(I implemented UI for my IME several days ago)

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6375724/3436942

Comment: You might also have an issue if the user is using an external keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the perfect answer, but it might help. From what I gather, you are looking for the keyboard height?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16789324/3436942 suggests that this isn't quite as easy as you would hope, but may be a solution for you?

(1) [Is there any way in android to get the height of virtual keyboard of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device/16789324#16789324) 's answer here suggests using Viewtree Observer and global layout listener, where you could possibly 'flash' the keyboard on screen (not perfect, I know). Or maybe (somewhere else in the program) store this vairable in a pointer. Then find 'height difference'.

(2) the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6375724/3436942 says you can't, but maybe (again) find the height of your view instead?

Just suggestions, as it seems this question does not have an answer unfortunately.