# How to get the Height of Android Keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

How get height of Android Keyboard?

I try:

```
KeyboardView keyboardView = new KeyboardView(_activity.getApplicationContext(), null);
Log.i("","xxx height " + keyboardCustom.mKeyboardView.getHeight());
            Log.i("","xxx height " + keyboardCustom.mKeyboardView.getBottom());
```

But always get 0.

Comment: is your keyboard visible

Comment: Refer this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009487/get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-in-android

Comment: This is always the wrong question (particularly with floating keyboards). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Why do you want the height of the keyboard?

Comment: I need get height of virtual android keyboard for place some image over virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use OnGlobalLayoutListener for getting Keyboard height or implement above code snippet

- chatRootLayout is your xml root layout
- pass this rootLayout as parentLayout parameter in checkKeyboardHeight

  ```
   private void checkKeyboardHeight(final View parentLayout)
      {
        chatRootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
        {
              @Override
              public void onGlobalLayout() 
              {
                      Rect r = new Rect();

                      chatRootLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                      int screenHeight = chatRootLayout.getRootView().getHeight();
                      int keyboardHeight = screenHeight - (r.bottom);

                      if (previousHeightDiffrence - keyboardHeight > 50) 
                      {                           
                          // Do some stuff here
                      }

                      previousHeightDiffrence = keyboardHeight;
                      if (keyboardHeight> 100) 
                      {
                          isKeyBoardVisible = true;
                          changeKeyboardHeight(keyboardHeight);
                      } 
                      else
                      {
                          isKeyBoardVisible = false;
                      }
                  }
          });
  }
  ```

  Here is changeKeyboardHeight() method

  ```
  private void changeKeyboardHeight(int height) 
  {
      if (height > 100) 
      {
              keyboardHeight = height;
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, keyboardHeight);
              yourLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I use parentLayout as _activity.getWindow().getDecorView() and chatRootLayout as EditTextEx. And never call addOnGlobalLayoutListener

Comment: Call checkKeyboardHeight() method on your onCreate() and make sure that your parentLayout & chatRootLayout must be your xml root/main layout (whether it was Linear/Relative)..

Comment: I try get height of virtual keyboard for Unity3d. I dont`t have xml layout